# Batch insert python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Скиьте пример плиз Batch insert python 2.7
По определенному количеству записи в бд
Например по 500 штук за раз

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

#######################################################
### DB connection strings config
#######################################################
tns = """
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-db-scan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = my_service_name)
    )
  )
"""

usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://%s:%s@%s' % (usr, pwd, tns))

# read data from CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
# speed up inserts for strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769557/5741205
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
        for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
# dump data to SQL table, using 1000 rows chunks
df.to_sql('temp_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtyp,
          chunksize=1000)  # <--- NOTE: chunksize parameter
```